# PHP session stores variables but when changing page they disappear

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm creating an online store using ajax and php. My index has a login section that appears with ajax and also have a navigator bar that gets the name of the user when completes the login.

So, when you login to the page the form sends you to Login.php, where you can see the content of the session and the navigator bar changes as explained before.

I only had session_start() on the index page, and it worked fine; the SESSION stored everything I wanted and the navigation bar worked, showing the name. But then when I changed something with ajax and printed out the session (print_r($_SESSION)) it turned out that the session had disappeared and it wasn't defined.

A friend told me to put session_start() in every page, so I put it in the Login.php file and now the session variable appears to be empty right after the login, so the navigator bar doesn't even work.

Also, when refreshing the index after getting logged in, it doesn't stay logged at all.

So it appears that the Session stores the variables but they don't stay stored for long.

I'm trying to use the MVC scheme (it's an assignment) so I only use the session_start on the index and the login page, not on the "controllers" and the "views"

To sum up, my session works at the beggining, it stores data, I change to the second page and still works and after loading the page the content is gone and the session undefined, but if I write down "session_start()" on the second file it doesn't even work

Here is the code where I get info from the db. (I don't think it's usefull but)

```
function Login()
{
    // Skiping conection code

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE nombre = '$username' && password = '$password'";
    $resultat = mysqli_query($connexio,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($connexio));
    $usuaris = array();
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat))
    {
        $usuaris = $fila;
    }   
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $usuaris['ID'];
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usuaris['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $usuaris['Admin'];

    mysqli_close($connexio);
    return $usuaris;
}
```

Thanks for the attention

Comment: The login works, this code is just to see how I enter the data in the session variables

Comment: You need to use session_start() on each page who uses Sessions vars.

Comment: Do you call session_start() before you start inserting variables into $_SESSION?

Comment: Problem solved. I had to writestart_session() on every page that uses the SESSION variable. I had only written that on the two main pages, but I had to do it also on the views. Sorry for the easy/stupid problem and thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add following before session_start()

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/");
```

Comment: A somewhat more elaborate answer would probably be more helpful. Why do this?

Comment: Yes Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.

This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get(). 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php